# Loading failed for the script error in Mozilla firefox and internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, mozilla

I am doing some web scraping using javascript. I want to fetch a table from a website and then display its content after customizing.

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

    .capitalize {
        text-transform: capitalize;   
    }

</style>
<script>
    function getTable(){
        $.getJSON('https://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=' + encodeURIComponent('https://www.lvmpd.com/en-us/Pages/CurrentTraffic.aspx') + '&callback=?', function(data){
            var table = $(data.contents).find('table');
            table = table[0];
            table.id = "trafficTable";

            var count = 1;
            var column = table.childNodes[1];
            column.childNodes.forEach(function(item,index){
                item.id = "col" + count;
                count++;
            });

            var tableBody = table.childNodes[3];
            tableBody.className="capitalize";
            tableBody.childNodes.forEach(function(item, index){
                var row = item;
                var rowNo = index;
                row.childNodes.forEach(function(item, index){
                    if(index != 0 && index != 2){
                        var col = item;
                        col.id = "row_" + rowNo/2 + "_col_" + index;
                        col.textContent = col.textContent.toLowerCase();    
                    }
                    else{
                        item.className = "toBeRemoved";
                    }
                });
            });

            $('body').append(table);

            $("th.toBeRemoved").remove();

            $("td.toBeRemoved").remove();

            $("#row_0_col_1").text("Incident Date");

            $("#row_0_col_3").text("Incident");

            $("#row_0_col_4").text("Incident Address");             

        });     
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        getTable();
    });
</script>
```

My code is successfully working in 'google chrome'
I got the table according to my need. But when i run the same page on Mozilla Firefox, Internet Explorer, Microsoft Edge they all does not load my script. I have looked for some solutions on the web explaining to check to run mozilla firefox in safe mode by disableing all the add-ons. But it didn't work for me.

So, And I also do think this is not some add-on problem. Because 3 browsers are having this issue.

The error i encounter is:

**Loading failed for the `<script>` with source “https://www.whateverorigin.org/get?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.lvmpd.com%2Fen-us%2FPages%2FCurrentTraffic.aspx&callback=jQuery331022927277922356082_1528914510052&_=1528914510053”.**

I need any proper solution that can make my code compatible with all the browsers.

Thanks